# Benchmark - combine two reports with same name

Tags: ruby, benchmarking

In ruby's benchmark:

```
Benchmark.benchmark { |b| 2.times { b.report('1') { sleep 0.1 } } }
```

Calling `b.report('1')` in the `2.times` iteration causes two separate reports.

Is there a way to combine these into a single report dynamically, on-the-fly?

Comment: I've got this strange feeling of déjà vu ;-)

Comment: Benchmark shows each report as soon as the measurements are done. You would have to somehow collect the intermediate results and add the combined result afterwards. Benchmark doesn't seem to support this.